# Passing mongoose item id to route in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

I am currently using mongoose, which is generating automatically id for my data item, which are in form of alphanumeric
 `_id: "560e617a7f84101a6bf85c37"`.

I have configured ui-router as

```
state('showallitems.edititem', {
    controller: 'ModalCtrl',
    url: "/editItem/:id",
    template: ""
  });
```

And html:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"ui-sref="showallitems.edititem({id: {{item._id}} })">Edit item!</a>
```

The problem that is that the _id property is being converted to INTEGER, and it becomes infinite. How can i avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I already used that way and it works for me...

My code:

angular version **"~1.3.15"**

angular-ui-router **"~0.2.10"**

mongoose version **"~3.8.0"**

MongoDB shell version: **2.4.14**

**Route**

```
.state('main.installation.form', {
    url: '/form/:installationId',
    views: {
      'container@main': {
        templateUrl: 'app/installation/installation.form.html',
        controller: 'InstallationFormCtrl'
      }
    }
})
```

**list.html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="installation in installations">
    <td class="col-md-2">{{installation.name}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-9">{{installation.description}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-1 text-center">
      <a class="cursor-pointer" title="Editar" ng-click="editInstallation(installation)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**list.controller.js**

```
$scope.installations = [];

installationFactory.listAll().get().$promise.then(function(response){
    $scope.installations = response;
});

$scope.editInstallation = function(installation) {
    $state.go('main.installation.form', { installationId: installation._id } );
};
```

**form.controller.js**

```
$scope.installation = {};

if($stateParams.installationId){
    installationFactory.findById().get({installation: $stateParams.installationId}).$promise.then(function(response){
      $scope.installation = response;
    });
}
```

And URL is:
[image: URL of my app with _id in route]